# Getting incorrect number of rows when using LIMIT in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp, sql-limit

I recently installed XAMPP to do some web development practice and am having issues with the following query in PHPMyAdmin.

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT f.name
FROM forums f
INNER JOIN messages m USING (forum_id)
ORDER BY m.date_entered
LIMIT 5
```

I get the [following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaQnW.jpg). Where more than 5 rows are displayed. However, when I replace the join with `INNER JOIN messages m ON m.forum_id = f.forum_id` I get the [desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VFHR.jpg).

Also, if I check 'Show All' when using `USING (forum_id)` the correct number of rows, 5, are displayed.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled XAMPP after backing up my tables, but the issue persists.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can yo provide us with a running [**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: @1000111 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e120/2/0

Answer (score 0):

Try doing Limit 0,5
Instead of just Limit 5